# Why does setting initialFirstResponder have no effect?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, first-responder

I have a simple form (NSWindow) with 3 text fields. NSWindow's `initialFirstResponder` is 'pointing' to the first field (`NSTextField`). All three text fields are circularly linked to each other via `nextKeyView`.

Problem that I have is that when I start the application from Xcode it'll focus on the text field that was last active (in focus) when the application closed.

So for example, if I name text fields A, B and C and `initialFirstResponder` is set to A. Now if I start the application, focus on B, and close the application, next time I start it, the focus will be on B.

Why is that and how would I fix this?

(Sorry if this is a trivial question, these are my first steps in cocoa...)

**EDIT:**

This is on OS X Lion 10.7.1, Xcode 4.1.

**EDIT 2:**

I found a way to "fix" this... In the main window (or any window for that matter) XIB/NIB file, click on "Attributes Inspector", then uncheck "Restorable" box. Now the application will not store the last position and so the `initialFirstResponder` seeing will be respected and followed accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Cocoa! :) I suspect this is happening as part of the new [user interface preservation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26) features in OS X Lion. (In fact, I just created a simple app with 3 text fields, and I see this behavior too.) Because [windows automatically restore themselves](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/DocumentBasedDesign/DocumentBasedDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH5-SW15), you will see a lot of this behavior happening automatically even if you didn't implement it. This is probably desirable — most applications will work this way, and the user will come to expect it.

However, if you *really* want to disable it, you can probably do so by subclassing NSWindow or perhaps NSTextField and overriding [`-encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:). But, I definitely recommend you leave the default behavior alone.

---

Edit with a little further information: the app state seems to be stored in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.yourapp.savedState`. There you can see a plist file with information about the windows. The other files don't seem easily readable, but they probably contain information about which field is first responder, etc.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thanks for explaining, as I was going mad looking for typos, etc... So it's not a bug, it's a feature :)

Comment: just an update, I think I found a way to enforce this behaviour... in the Attributes Inspector there's a Restorable chechkbox. Unticking it seems to to the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Despite this thread being almost 10 years old I'll gonna add an answer. Just about one month after the answer from jbandes OS X 10.7 Lion was introduced.

Following a quote from `NSWindowRestoration.h`

```
@interface NSWindow (NSUserInterfaceRestoration)

/* Determines whether the window should be restored on relaunch.  By default, windows with NSTitledWindowMask set in the styleMask are restorable, and windows without it set are not.
 */
@property (getter=isRestorable) BOOL restorable API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7));
```